# Newbie on RubyOnRails . How to edit site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How do you edit the website after it has been launched on Heroku?
The rubyonrails tutorial explains how to launch the original but not how to edit.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by edit? How you update the files on heroku, or how you update the content displayed on your website?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the code on your local machine, commit it to git, and then git push to Heroku, just as you did to get the original site up.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code and commit the changes with:

```
git commit -a -m "my edit description"
```

Updating code on Heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```